# IDBWrapper (indexedDB) doesn't work in Safari (Private Window) and in iframe on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, safari, indexeddb

I have the issue with IDBWrapper functionality in Safari  (Private Window) and in the iframe on iOS.
Error message:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'a').

In another browsers and devices, everything works well.

I have used IDBWrapper 1.6.0 version. In the latest version (1.7.1) I have the same issue.

How can I solve this issue? Do you have any suggestions?
Please check the simple code example below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/idbwrapper/1.6.0/idbstore.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

-

```
var customers = new IDBStore({
  dbVersion: 1,
  storeName: 'customer',
  keyPath: 'id',
  autoIncrement: true,
  onStoreReady: function(){
    console.log('Store ready!');
  }
});
```

You can check it on this page: https://gist.github.com/jensarps/1391434#file-index-html

Thanks!